# My anaconda navigator won't reopen after installation

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

When i install anaconda on my pc(windows 8), it opens but if i close it and try to use it again i keep getting this, see image attached
Then after few minutes it's shows navigation error 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7bgm.jpg)

Comment: Anaconda issues should be directed to the [`anaconda-issues` repository](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues).